# Formatting time on Android, while following preferences (24 hr clock vs. AM/PM, etc..)

Tags: android, time, date-format

I'm currently using the following code to format time on Google Android:

```
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(millis)
```

While this code honors my timezone and locale settings, it ignores the '24 hour mode' setting in system preferences, always returning time in AM/PM. Is there any way to get time in the same format as that on the status bar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In theory (never tried this yet), you can use

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

To get formatters based on your settings.  YMMV.

Comment: Specifically the DateFormat.is24HourFormat method

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context))

Answer (score 4):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
df.format(new Date(date));
```

"date" in millisec

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.